# Display local pages with fully functional browser

Tags: android

I originally started out displaying a web page in the assets folder using a WebView. However I seem to have grown beyond that as my page is not behaving as I would expect. According to the developer docs WebView should only be used for static pages that have no interactions. CSS, javascript etc. are not enabled. This makes sense with the behavior I am seeing. While my page renders nicely in the dev environment browser it looks like plain HTML on the device with no css or javascript capabilities. So if I want to display a local (assets folder) html page with css and javascript etc. enabled how would I go about doing that? I assume tutorials exist for such a simple thing but my Googling is coming up empty.

On the off chance my links as bad here is the header.

```
<head>
     <link href="folderA/folderB/file.css" rel="stylesheet" />

     <script src="folderA/js/file.js"></script>
</head>
```

Thank You again for helping this noob.
JB

Just found this. Might be on the right track?
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to the developer docs WebView should only be used for static pages that have no interactions

Citation, please. I have never seen such a claim, and there are many, many applications that use `WebView` with "interactions".

> CSS, javascript etc. are not enabled

CSS is most certainly enabled -- in fact, AFAIK, there is no way to disable it even if you wanted to. JavaScript is disabled by default, but a simple call to `getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` on your `WebView` will enable it.

> So if I want to display a local (assets folder) html page with css and javascript etc. enabled how would I go about doing that?

`loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")` works, to load an `index.html` file in the root of your project's `assets/` directory.

For example, in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite/T12-Book), I load `file:///android_asset/book/0.htm` (and other HTML files) into `WebView` widgets loaded into a `ViewPager`. Each HTML refers to a pair of CSS stylesheets using:

```
<link href="0.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="pgepub.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

In [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/WebView/GeoWeb1), I load some HTML out of assets and use some in-page JavaScript.

Now, I have not done much with directory structures inside of `assets/` and trying to access things across directories. It is conceivable that you are running into some problem related to that.

Comment: Under Basic Usuage "By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine; the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it, and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a WebView"

Comment: @user1278561: That does not say that "WebView should only be used for static pages that have no interactions". Moreover, consider that the Browser application **uses `WebView` for its rendering**. What this passage is stating is that handling all capabilities of a Web browser is *hard*, so the richer the experience you need, the more you might want to consider just using a browser app rather than trying to reproduce all the browser-support code yourself.

Comment: Enabling Javascript did it. I apologize if I was confusing / confused. this is not the first, and likely the last the Android dev docs have confused me.

Comment: Fair enough....but what is a browser app? Do they mean a third party browser app with an API you can use or is there another Android control say <WebBrowser />.

Comment: @user1278561: A browser app is an app that serves as a Web browser. There are dozens of them available for Android, and one (or more) comes by default on every Android device. If you want to embed Web rendering in your app, you use `WebView` -- if you just want to display the Web content identified by a URL, use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` and `startActivity()` to start up the user's choice of browser.

Comment: AHHHH so whatever they have like Dolphin, Opera, Chrome etc. It'll use that. I done been edjumakated.